# I am working with query where i am getting count on dates when there is a campaign i also wanna get count 0 if there is no campaign on date range

Tags: mysql, sql

Date Range is last seven days. currently i am getting this data from this query

```
counts dates
1      2018-12-25
1      2018-12-26
3      2018-12-30
```

query is

```
select COALESCE(Count(campaign_id), 0) as counts,date(start_date) as dates from campaigns where segment_id=30 
and date(start_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
group by date(start_date)
```

but i want expected output is

```
counts dates
0      2018-12-24
1      2018-12-25
1      2018-12-26
0      2018-12-27
0      2018-12-28
0      2018-12-29
3      2018-12-30
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Thanks i managed to solve problem at application level

Answer (score 1):

You can generate 7 rows by using `information_schema`'s views such as `information_schema.tables`

```
select (select count(*) 
          from campaigns
         where start_date = e.dates
        ) count,
        e.dates
  from
  (
    select * 
      from campaigns c   
      right join
        (
        SELECT  @cr := @cr + 1 as rn,       
                date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 - @cr day) as dates
          from information_schema.tables c1 
         cross join (SELECT @cr := 0, @segID := 30) r
        where @cr<7
        ) d on c.campaign_id = d.rn
    where coalesce(c.segment_id,@segID) = @segID
   ) e;

count   dates
  0   24.12.2018 
  1   25.12.2018 
  1   26.12.2018 
  0   27.12.2018 
  0   28.12.2018 
  0   29.12.2018 
  3   30.12.2018
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/WNSJ12645)

Answer (score 0):

You need a way of generating all the dates.  The standard answer is to use a `left join` and a calendar table or other table with the dates you want.

In your case, your table may already have the all the dates.  If so, the simplest method is conditional aggregation:

```
select date(start_date) as dates,
       sum(segment_id = 30) cnt_30
from campaigns
where start_date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day) and
      start_date < date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day)
group by date(start_date);
```

You'll notice that I also modified the `where` clause, by removing the function calls on `start_date`.  This allows the MySQL optimizer to use an index, if one is available.